# Trying to use a variable over multiple classes

Tags: php

At the moment, I am initiating my DB connectiong via each function in my MVC like so:

```
<?php

class System extends Controller
{

    public static function get($info = '')
    {
        try
        {
            if($info):
                 $database = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();
                 $get_info = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM site"); //get all the info from the datbase
                 $result = $get_info->execute(array($info)); //run the query
                 $information = $result->fetch(); //fetch the information
                 return $information->$info; //return the info to use on other parts of the site
            else:
                throw new Exception("There was an error selecting site information");
            endif;

        }catch(Exception $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}

?>
```

which means I would need to use

```
$database = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();
```

in each and every function. Now I am trying to initiate the database variable in my controller (my controller extends all classes) so I can just do $database->prepare rather than initiate it in each function. What would be a way to this>

I have tried

```
var $database = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();
```

**and**

```
public $database = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();
```

with no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it during initialization because member variable initialization must be static, and you're trying to call a function. From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php):

> This declaration may include an initialization, but this
>   initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to
>   be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time
>   information in order to be evaluated.

Instead, do it in the [constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php):

```
class Controller {
    protected $database;
    function __construct() {
        $this->database = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried, and got this error: <b>Fatal error</b>:  Using $this when not in object context

Comment: @randommmmm - Make sure your method is within the class and its not declared as `static`. The constructor should be defined as `function __construct()` and nothing else (unless you're supplying the constructor with parameters).